# convert an array to a string from a web service request C#

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have a php web service that I have tried to consume and parse data to my textbox in designer(I work on a windows 10 app store application),this is my code:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public string uriString = "my URL";
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            Getdata();
        }

        private async void Getdata()
        {
            var http = new HttpClient();
            http.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;
            System.Collections.ArrayList response = new System.Collections.ArrayList(new string[] { await http.GetStringAsync(uriString) });
            var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Sponsorises.RootObject>(response); //the error is here
            sponsorname.Text = rootObject.nom; //the name of my textBox
        }
        public class Sponsorises
     {

    internal class RootObject
    {
        public string nom { get; set; }
        public string tel { get; set; }
        public string photo { get; set; }
        public string sponsorise_adrs { get; set; }

    }
}
```

this is my json code:

```
 {
success: 1,
message: "sponsorise found!",
total: 1,
sponsorises: [
{
nom: "my third local",
tel: "88888888",
photo: "http://192.168.1.1/1446241709_ab_cart2_bleu2.png",
sponsorise_adrs: "the adress"
}
]
}
```

I am having problem in converting arraylist response to the string rootObject,have you please any idea
thanks for help

Comment: What is the 'problem'? Any exceptions?

Comment: I have an error :"can not convert 'System.Collections.arrayList' to string in the line of affecting response to rootObject

Comment: That error seems pretty clear to me. What have you tried to solve it?

Comment: I tried to do this line: List<string> rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Sponsorises.RootObject>(response);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add another class for `sponsorises`:

```
internal class RootObject
{
    public string success { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string total { get; set; }
    public List<Sponsorise> sponsorises { get; set; }
}

class Sponsorise
{
    public string nom { get; set; }

    public string tel { get; set; }

    public string photo { get; set; }

    public string sponsorise_adrs { get; set; }
}
```

And deserialize like so:

```
var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response); 
sponsorname.Text = rootObject.sponsorises[0].nom;
```

Comment: thanks Sir for your code but If I apply it I get an other error which is: RootObject doesn't contain a definition for nom :(

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that JsonConvert.Deserialize() expects a string, not an array list.

This can be done by not casting your web response to ArrayList

```
var response = await http.GetStringAsync(uriString);
var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response);
```

Comment: thanks Sir for your reply,I thought that sponsorises is an array :/

Answer (score 1):

Add that to the beginning of each RootObject attribute:

```
[JsonProperty("fieldName")]
```